# location.href with a jquery handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the next code.

```
$(function(){
    var cambio=false;
        var codigoAlumno="";
        $("select").change(function(){
             codigoAlumno=$(this).val();
             cambio=true;
        });

        $("#insertar").on('click',function(){
            alert("has hecho click");
            alert(cambio);
            if(cambio===true){
                window.location.href='../../Servlet?submit=Insertar Alumnos&codigoA='+codigoAlumno;
            }
        });
    });
```

I want that when it's a change in my select catch the value and when i submit with the button pass it to my servlet.

If i put location.href outside of the handler it works but when it's in no.

When it's inside even I tried to go to other page and it doesn't work either

Comment: thanks buddy i choose the incorrect one

Comment: Did you check if the object with the ID insertar exists when the event handler have been to attach

Comment: yeah it shows both alerts when i clicked the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `return false`.

```
  if(cambio===true){
       window.location.href='../../Servlet?submit=Insertar Alumnos&codigoA='+codigoAlumno;
       return false;  
    }
```